# Copy&Paste Data Multiple Criteria Excel

Tags: excel, copy, paste

I need to copy information from one table into another table and i am not sure how to do that.

So that would be my initial table:

```
        Date 1  Date 2  Date 3
Part A    122    134      1212
Part B    453     3       4536
Part C    35      23      3
```

I need to copy that information into another table with different outline:

```
                   Part A     Part B    Part C
          Info 1    -            -        -
Date1     Info 2    122         453
          Info 3     -           -         -
          Info 1     -           -         - 
Date 2    Info 2    134         3
          Info 3     -           -        -
          Info 1     -           -         - 
Date 3    Info 2    1212       4536
          Info 3
```

How could i copy& paste the information into the new table?I think Index Match would work but not sure how.

Comment: Playa a bit with a Pivot until you make it in the target outline. Then copy and paste.

Comment: My favorite would be an macro that search through the whole table and just finds the correct cell where to copy&paste.

Comment: ok, what have you done so far?

Comment: But the data will change from time to time and more data will be added. Then i would need a macro to create the pivot.

Comment: I am not that good with macros. My idea so far was a match index funtion

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you table starts from cell `A1` as below,

[image]

Enter the formula in cell `C2` as below,

`=IF(MOD(ROW(),3)=0,OFFSET(Sheet5!$A$1,(COLUMN()-2),(ROW()/3)),"")`
[image]

Drag it to the right and then down to complete the range. This formula refers `Sheet5` which you can change it per your needs.